# Не могу создать динамический двумерный масив

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++

Нужно чтобы пользователь ввел количество строк (а) и столбцов (b), чтобы создать двумерный массив. Пробовал разными способами - не выходит.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int r;
int c;

cout << "a: ";
cin >> r;

cout << "b: ";
cin >> c;

int *A = new int[r][c];

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: что есть "не выходит"?

Comment: Попробуйте так: int *A = new int[r\*c];

Comment: @Igor например конкретно в моем случае VisualStudio ругается на:
1) Ошибка C2540 неконстантное выражение используется в качестве границы массива
2) Ошибка C2440 инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "int (*)[1]" в "int *"

Comment: @DavidRJ ну мы же и обсуждаем "конкретно Ваш случай". Добавьте это в вопрос.

Comment: Сначала аллоцируете с помощью new одномерный массив указателей на int. Затем в цикле для каждого указателя выделяете память под одномерный массив. В результате это будет работать подобно двумерному массиву.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky можно пример кода?

Comment: @DavidRJ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то, если это C++ - то лучше

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix(rows,vector<int>(cols));
```

Ну, а если в стиле C - то

```
int ** matrix = new int*[rows];
for(int i = 0; i < cols; ++i) matrix[i] = new int[cols];
```

Comment: Спасибо, но а как тогда обращаться к елементу?

Comment: `matrix[row][col]`, как обычно :)